# Separate functionalities of little AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I write an application to learn AngularJS:

**family_tree.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>


<p>First step in Angular.js !</p>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-click="update_name(person.name)" id="{{person.id}}" ng-repeat="person in persons">
        Name = {{ person.name }} - Father = {{ person.father}} -
        Mother = {{ person.mother}}
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="personCtrl">
    Name: <input id="nameChanger" type="text" ng-model="name_to_change">
    <input type="button" ng-click="change_name()" value="Update">
  </div>

  </div>
</div>


<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);



</script>

<script src="./family_displayer.js"></script>
<script src="./name_updater.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**family_displayer.js**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$http',function($rootScope, $http){    
    $rootScope.update_name = function(name) {
        $rootScope.name_to_change = name;
    }

    $http.get('./data.json').success(function(json) {
        var persons; 
        for(var i in json){
            persons = json[i].person;
        }
        var tmp = new Array();
        for(var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {       
            var obj = {name : persons[i].name,
                       father : persons[i].father,
                       mother : persons[i].mother};
            tmp[persons[i].id] = obj;
        }
        var families = new Array();
        for(var i = 1; i < tmp.length; i++) {
            var name = tmp[i].name;
            var father = "X", mother = "X";
            if(tmp[i].father != undefined) {
                father = persons[tmp[i].father-1].name;         
            }
            if(tmp[i].mother != undefined) {
                mother = persons[tmp[i].mother-1].name;         
            }
            var obj = {
                id : i,
                name : tmp[i].name,
                father : father,
                mother : mother}
            families.push(obj);
            $rootScope.persons = families;

        }

    });
}]);
```

**name_updater.js**

```
app.controller('personCtrl', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.change_name = function() {
        var old_name = $rootScope.name_to_change;
        var new_name = document.getElementById("nameChanger").value;
        console.log("Change " + old_name + "by " + new_name);
        for(var i = 0 ; i < $rootScope.persons.length; i++) {
            if($rootScope.persons[i].name == old_name) $rootScope.persons[i].name = new_name;
            else if ($rootScope.persons[i].father == old_name) $rootScope.persons[i].father = new_name;
            else if($rootScope.persons[i].mother == old_name) $rootScope.persons[i].mother = new_name;
        }
        document.getElementById("nameChanger").value = "";

    }
}]);
```

It's display informations about some families (gived by a JSON File) in a list and if we click on somenone on the list (so on a li element), we can change his name and this change will be visible on the previous list. My main problem is that everything is on same page (displayer and updater).

I would like to refresh the page when you clicked on a person in order to show only the name to change and once it's done, get back to the displaying list with the new name. I already separate the way of displaying and update in two controllers but I don't know how to implement the previous scenario that I described in order to do not have the all on the same page.

Comment: Just a comment, be careful of using the `rootscope` so much, would suggest using services for stuff you want to share across the entire app.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but my app is kind little :)

Comment: Just a suggestion for future working with angular, it's better practice to break this sort of logic into angular services, that is what they are there for. Especially if you are learning, check factories/services/providers out. They will help you out a lot.

Comment: You could use ng-show or ng-hide to display only what you want. Otherwise, look at ng-route to redirect the user to an other page when he clicks on someone on the list and display the proper template on a ng-view. Read the doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView. Hope this helps you.